# How do I respect the whitespace inside a span using Vue 3?

Tags: vue.js

There are a lot of places in our code where we have leading/trailing space inside of spans and other tag elements. This worked when we were using Vue 2 but in the process of upgrading to Vue 3 the spacing is not being respected in the following code:

```html
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></span><span v-cloak>  {{cartName}}</span>
```

Any solutions out there that can address this problem?

We are using cdjns and don't have a vue.config file so I have tried both

`app.config.compilerOptions.whitespace = 'preserve';`
`app.config.compilerOptions.whitespace = 'condense';`

I had no luck using either of the above compiler options. When I hardcode a name value in place of `{{cartName}}` it respects the spacing just fine so Vue is trimming the lead space.

**Result:** *CartIcon*CartName

**Expected:** *CartIcon* CartName

Comment: I would love to not have to go through our entire project and manually make this change everywhere :-)

Comment: Why not just do `span[v-cloak] { padding-left: 1em; }` in your CSS?

Comment: The tag isn't always a span and doesn't always have v-cloak directive.

Comment: You can use Non-breaking Space `&nbsp;` to create white space.

Comment: Don't depend on the HTML to keep the spacing. Use a class with padding or margin.

Answer (score 1):

The most straightforward way to ensure that whitespace is preserved in Vue 3 is to use CSS. Specifically, you can apply the `white-space` property to your `<span>` tag to prevent the whitespace from being collapsed.

Here's how you could do it:

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></span>
<span v-cloak class="preserve-space">{{ cartName }}</span>
```

And in your CSS:

```
.preserve-space {
  white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[Vue SFC Playground](https://play.vuejs.org/#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)

Use `v-html` together with `white-space:break-spaces`:

```
<span v-cloak style="white-space: break-spaces" v-html="` ${cartName}`"></span>
```

But personally I use `&nbsp;`:

[Vue SFC Playground](https://play.vuejs.org/#eNqFUrFOwzAQ/RXLAwGJtkJsaakEiAEGqCijFze5pm4d2/I5pVWUf+eckNChKpt97927Z7+r+aNz430FPOUzzLxygSGEys2FUaWzPrCaeVizhq29LVlC1GSAnqUP77KEX2w86QtRMZkKk1mDgWU97SFKXSeRxWIhuRFmNunG0kC6BCidlgHoNkMnDcNw1PAg+Mr6HHx65w4MrVY5K7w8TgWfz6L6yET5dDhSQz9U8MmcZpBW1JycDOC3PCA5XKtivEVr6AtqYRijXls6pcF/uKDoBYKnrEUiJrW2329tLfgKbvt6toFsd6a+xUOsCb7wgOD3ZGjAgvQFhA5+Wb7Dgc4DWNq80sS+AH4C/UUVPXa0p8rkZPuE17p9bdNSpvjCl0MAg/2jotHIbFq+4JTa84Wn/9m9H9+3fcI09IunqZ/ZoxzWysDCW4fXdR9LugyeHDU3U/bvDmRaIlKkhT66jaLE2HAa4cY6R0KjKBzXoYu6a9yPMm3lbn5lVuim9TC8ac5tBG9+AGhhDKc=)

```
<span v-cloak>&nbsp;{{cartName}}</span>
```